# Auto generation of meta description

Tags: magento-1.9

i want auto generation of meta description for my products
liks this:
Buy {product name} for Rs {price} at sitename.com | New Book | Authorised seller for {publihser}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an observer on the event `catalog_product_save_before` with this code:

```
public function autoMetaDescription($observer) {
     $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
     $metaDescription = "Buy ". $product->getName()." for Rs ".number_format($product->getFinalPrice(), 2)." at sitename.com | New Book | Authorised seller for ". $product->getAttributeText('publisher');
    $product->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);
}
```

Of course you may need some changes if the website is multilanguage. You have to check on which language you are saving the product.

Comment: @Dinesh [see here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) how you can create an observer for an event.

Comment: which file i have to done modification

Comment: You don't need to edit any file. You need to create one. Check the tutorial I gave you to see how you should create an observer for an event. There is no point in replicating what is there

Comment: try this but not working can you tell some detail, i am not understanding tutorial so much for my use because i am new to magneto/programming